# Execution Timed Out (12000 ms): How can I optimize JS kata to run faster? [Upside-Down Numbers - Challenge Edition]

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
    function upsideDown(x, y) {
      const list = ["0", "1", "6", "8", "9"];
      let count = 0;
      for (let i = parseInt(x); i <= parseInt(y); i++) {
        let curr = i.toString().split("");
        let upsideDownCurr = "";
        if (
          !curr.every(function (x) {
            return list.includes(x);
          })
        )
          continue; // Skips if number includes non-upDown num
        for (let j = 0; j < curr.length; j++)
          if (curr[j] === "6") upsideDownCurr = "9" + upsideDownCurr;
          else if (curr[j] === "9") upsideDownCurr = "6" + upsideDownCurr;
          else upsideDownCurr = `${curr[j]}` + upsideDownCurr;
        if (upsideDownCurr === curr.join("")) count++;
      }
      return count;
    }
```

Input:

Your function will receive two strings, each comprised of digits representing a positive integer. These two values will represent the upper and lower bounds of a range.
Output:

Your function must return the number of valid upside down numbers within the range of the two input arguments, including both upper and lower bounds.
What is an Upside-Down Number?

An upside down number is an integer that appears the same when rotated 180 degrees, as illustrated below.

This works fine untill
`Test.assertEquals(upsideDown('100000','12345678900000000'),718650)`
any idea how to optimize the code?

Comment: So "upside-down" means "same left-to-right as right-to-left". I really dislike those "kata" things sometimes because there's no rigor to the terminology.

Comment: @Pointy Not exactly. If I understand well, 6 becomes 9 for example...

Comment: @Damien OK well what does "2" become? or "5"?

Comment: nothing, in case if 2 or 5 is in the number it should skip to next number. only 6 and 9 needs to be changed.

Comment: OK well that's totally not at all clear from the description of the problem, which was entirely my point.

Comment: You're dealing with palindrome numbers, except that the 69 digit (which I'll call `X`) can't be the middle digit of a number with an odd number of digits. So `1X1` is not valid, but `1XX1` is valid and counts as two numbers: `1691` and `1961`. There are three one-digit numbers: 0, 1, 8. Four two digit numbers: 11, 88, XX (assuming numbers with leading zeros like 00 don't count). To make three-digit numbers, you take the two-digit numbers and put a valid digit in the middle, so `1y1`, `8y8`, `XyX` where `y` is 0, 1, or 8. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**  Per comment from user3386109, clarifying flippable vs spinnable ("upside down" or rotation by 180 degrees).

The real issue is the shear size of the upper bound of your test, which is ~1.2 x 10^16.  If the iteration can process even 1 billion numbers per second, then the algorithm as-is will take ~12,000,000 seconds of processing which is ~138 days.  Hence why the algorithm is timing out...

If you restrict the range of numbers to the permutation of the 5 digits that are spinnable, the number of permutations is 2 x 5^16 or 305,175,781,250.  (The 2 represents the first digit which can be 0 or 1, and the 5^16 represents the 5 possibilities (ie, 0,1,6,8,9) for each of the remaining 16 digits.)  This is much more manageable to calculate in a somewhat reasonable time...

So, if following the path of iterating over the range of numbers, only generate the possibilities given the spinnable digits (ie, 0,1,6,8,9) rather than walking the entire range of numbers...

Even better, though, if you're simply looking for the count of numbers fully spinnable, then there is little need to actually iterate over the range when with a bit of logic and math you can calculate the possibilities as just exemplified.  More specifically, let's say you wish to count the number of spinnable 5 digit numbers, that is, in the range 10000 - 99999.

- First, the spinnable digits have to be split into those that are "self spinning", and those that are "mirror pairs".  Ie, 0,1,8 spin back to themselves and 6/9 form a mirror pair.
- Then, simply calculate the possibilities for each of the five digits:

  - Digit 4: Can be 1,6,8,9 (4 possibilities)
  - Digit 3: Can be 0,1,6,8,9 (5 possibilities)
  - Digit 2: Can only be 0, 1, 8 (3 possibilites)  This is the center digit of a 5 digit number, and therefore it can't be 6 or 9 as the center digit must be self spinning.
  - Digit 1: Must be the same as Digit 3.  (1 possibility)
  - Digit 0: Must be the same as Digit 4.  (1 possibility)
  - So, the number of 5 digit numbers that are spinnable is...

    - 4 * 5 * 3 * 1 * 1  -or-  60 spinnable numbers.

The above is just the algorithm based on the number of digits involved.  If as in the question the range involves a 17 digit number then one must iterate over the range of digits, summing along the way.  Ie,

- 1 digit (0 - 9):  3 spinnable numbers
- 2 digit (10 - 99):  4 * 1  -or- 4 spinnable numbers
- 3 digit (100 - 999):  4 * 3 * 1  -or-  12 spinnable numbers
- 4 digit (1000 - 9999):  4 * 5 * 1 * 1  -or-  20 spinnable numbers

  o

  o

  o
- 15 digit ( 100000000000000 - 999999999999999):  4 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 3 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1  -or-  187,500 spinnable numbers-
- 16 digit ( 1000000000000000 - 9999999999999999):  4 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1  -or-  312,500 spinnable numbers

I'll stop here, as now there needs to be some further consideration when dealing with the last range, as typically the full width of digits (in the case of the question, 17 digits) does not run the entire range of 17 digits.  Ie, the range is from 10000000000000000 - 12345678900000000 rather than 99999999999999999.  In this case the algorithm proposed can still be employed, but must now take into account the limits imposed by each digit in the 17 digit number...

**EDIT 2**:  Following up on the prior proposed strategy, the code snippet below incorporates both the logic of calculating the spinners for each range of digits leading up to the full width of the number and the spinners for the full width of the number.  That is, this is by necessity a two stage algorithm, as the second stage when dealing with the full width of the number must take into account that the trailing digits of the number might not necessarily be within range of possible spinnable digits at the head of the number.  Thus the second stage must calculate the spinners at each range of increasing resolution...

The console output from the code snippet will likely be more explicative than a paragraph of words attempting to explain the concept behind the second stage, particularly the example of number 189942.

```js
function calcSpinners( x ) {
  const selfies = [ 0, 1, 8 ];
  const mirrors = [ [ 6, 9 ] ];
  
  // Stage 1.  Walk from 1 digit up to n - 1 digits, calculating the number
  // of possible spinners at each step and adding to the total
  let n = x.toString().length;
  let sum1 = 0;
  
  for ( let i = 1; i < n; i++ ) {
    let count = 1;
    // If an even number of digits, then there is no center digit.  If an odd
    // number of digits, then let's factor in the number of possible selfies.
    count = count * ( i % 2 === 0 ? 1 : selfies.length );
    
    let halfDigits = i / 2 |0;
    if ( 0 < halfDigits ) {
      count = count * ( selfies.filter( sx => sx !== 0 ).length + mirrors.length * 2 );
      count = count * ( selfies.length + mirrors.length * 2 ) ** ( halfDigits - 1 );
    }
    console.log( `Range ${10n ** BigInt( i - 1)} - ${10n ** BigInt( i ) - 1n} has ${count} spinners` );
    sum1 += count;
  }
  
  console.log( `Subtotal of spinners from 1 to ${n-1} digits: ${sum1}` );
  
  // Stage 2:  Now we're just dealing with the full width of x.  Eg, if x is 17
  // digits, then the evaluation of the spinnable numbers is evaluated at each
  // range of increasing resolution of x, always 17 digits.
  
  let sum2 = 0;
  n = BigInt( x.toString().length );
  let loopTill = n / 2n + ( n % 2n );
  
  for ( let i = 0n; i <= loopTill; i++ ) {
    let dhi = 10n ** ( n - i - 1n );
    let dlo = dhi * 10n
    
    let hi = ( i === loopTill ? x : ( x / dhi ) * dhi - 1n );
    let lo = ( i === 0n ? dhi : ( x / dlo ) * dlo );
    
    count = 0;
    if ( lo < hi ) {
      let hiNum = hi.toString().split( '' ).map( x => parseInt( x ) );
      let loNum = lo.toString().split( '' ).map( x => parseInt( x ) );

      // If an even number of digits, then there is no center digit.  If an odd
      // number of digits, then let's factor in the number of possible selfies.
      let center = hiNum.length / 2 |0;
      count = ( hiNum.length % 2 === 0 ? 1 : selfies.filter( sx => loNum[ center ] <= sx && sx <= hiNum[ center ] ).length );

      for ( let j = 0; j < center; j++ ) {
        hiNumHiDigit = hiNum[ j ];
        hiNumLoDigit = hiNum[ hiNum.length - 1 - j ];
        loNumHiDigit = loNum[ j ];
        loNumLoDigit = loNum[ loNum.length - 1 - j ];
        
        // For the digit in question, count the number of possible selfie and
        // mirror digits.
        let eligible =
          selfies.filter( sx =>
            loNumHiDigit <= sx && sx <= hiNumHiDigit
            && loNumLoDigit <= sx && sx <= hiNumLoDigit
            && !( sx === 0 && j === 0 )
          ).length
          + mirrors.filter( pair =>
            ( loNumHiDigit <= pair[ 0 ] && pair[ 0 ] <= hiNumHiDigit
            && loNumLoDigit <= pair[ 1 ] && pair[ 1 ] <= hiNumLoDigit )
          ).length 
          + mirrors.filter( pair =>
            ( loNumHiDigit <= pair[ 1 ] && pair[ 1 ] <= hiNumHiDigit
            && loNumLoDigit <= pair[ 0 ] && pair[ 0 ] <= hiNumLoDigit )
          ).length; 
        
        count = count * eligible;
      }
      
      console.log( `Range ${lo} - ${hi} has ${count} spinners.` );
      sum2 += count;
    }
  }
  
  console.log( `Subtotal of spinners of ${n} digits up to and including ${x}: ${sum2}` );
  console.log( `Total spinners: ${sum1 + sum2}` );
  return sum1 + sum2;
  
}

let loVal = 100000n;
let hiVal = 12345678900000000n;
console.log( `Calculating spinner count for ${loVal}.` );
let loTotal = calcSpinners( loVal );
console.log( `${loVal} has ${loTotal} spinners.` );
console.log( `` );

console.log( `Calculating spinner count for ${hiVal}.` );
let hiTotal = calcSpinners( hiVal );
console.log( `${hiVal} has ${hiTotal} spinners.` );
console.log( `` );

console.log( `Between ${loVal} - ${hiVal} there are ${hiTotal - loTotal} spinners.` );
console.log( `` );
console.log( `` );

let testVal = 189942n;
console.log( `Calculating spinner count for ${testVal}.` );
let testTotal = calcSpinners( testVal );
console.log( `${testVal} has ${testTotal} spinners.` );
console.log( `` );
```

Bottom line is that although this algorithm is more complex, it solves the problem in minimal time as it is not attempting to iterate over the entire range of numbers (or combination of spinnable digits) of the input number...

This question is a good example of having to refactor not the code, but rather the underlying algorithm, as a brute force approach does not scale on a classical computer...

Comment: I don't think that "vertically flippable" is the same as "rotated 180 degrees". For example 819 vertically flipped is 816, but the six would be backwards. 819 rotated 180 degrees is 618 and the 6 is correctly oriented. Of course 816 is not a valid "upside down" number by either method since it's not the same after the flip or the rotation. A valid upside down number would be 986 since rotating by 180 degrees results in 986.

Comment: @user3386109 good point of clarification, and i will tweak the response accordingly.  It still doesn't negate the general strategy proposed to increase the performance (central to the question), which by the down vote it's clear that someone can't see the forest through the trees...  This is one of those questions that I debate how far to take the answer not knowing how much guidance the OP is seeking...

Comment: Yes, the general strategy substantially reduces the problem size by halving the base from 10 to 5. Realiizing that the numbers are palindromes halves the number of digits from 16 to 8. Combine the two and you have only 5^8 = 390625 numbers to deal with. Have an upvote. Cheers